Сделать/делать when talking about ability to do something
I wanted to say, "I can do that (make coffee)" in Russian, and so I said "Это я могу делать." A Russian language speaker corrected me and said that I should instead use сделать. I don't doubt that that's correct, but the explanation that I got was that it was because I was "making and object" rather than "making an action" which I find confusing and unexpected assuming it was related to aspect/state of completion.
Could someone help me to understand the reason that I should be using сделать rather than делать?

Not being a native speaker, I'm going to comment and not answer, as I might get it wrong. The explanation "making an object" rather than "performing (not *making) an action" strikes me as nonsense. Russians don't necessary understand grammar simply by dint of being native speakers. It seems to me that сделать is talking about doing and completing the brewing of the cup of coffee, whereas делать, supposedly "a process" (although I often find that explanation of Russian grammar unhelpful as many counterexamples exist), is taking about the actual ability to perform the action in the abstract.

я могу это сделать - I can do that now for you. я могу это делать - I am able to make coffee - it is part of my skill-set. I might not be right on all of this, but a native speaker will give you the definitive answer.

Всё дело в том, что кофе варится, готовится  быстро. Поэтому лучше сказать: я могу сделать. А если хотите пояснить, что вы  специалист по приготовлению, лучше сказать: я умею готовить, варить кофе.

Most Russian verbs come in pairs that differ in the aspect. The aspect expresses how the action defined by the verb develops in time. Imperfective verbs define state, while the perfective ones define state transition. (Note that while technically correct, this is a very broad description that comes with a lot of gotchas)
In your example, сделать has the perfective aspect, while делать has the imperfective one. Very roughly, they correspond to English "to have something done, to see something through to completion" versus "to be doing something (over the time or repeatedly)". The former is the state transition from not done to done, the latter is a state of being doing something.
When you're saying я могу это делать, you mean "I can be doing this".
It would make sense if the act of brewing coffee were long:

— Кофе нужно постоянно мешать, а мне нужно сходить за продуктами. Кто будет мешать кофе, пока меня не будет?
— Я могу это делать

Or if you were assigning responsibilities on a camping site, one of them being "being in charge of coffee":

— Я буду рубить дрова, а Маша следить за костром. Кто будет варить кофе?
— Я могу это делать.

In your case, people were probably asking about having a cup of coffee done for them, which probably involved little more than putting a capsule into the machine and pressing a button.
The meaning you want to convey is "I can see to it that you have your coffee". This requires a perfective.

I was "making and object" rather than "making an action" which I find confusing and unexpected assuming it was related to aspect/state of completion.

I guess that was another way of saying what I just tried to convey, probably, equally confusing.

Thank you so much for your response! It’s very helpful to examples of appropriate contexts for both sentences. That’s what I find challenging: it’s not that it’s necessarily incorrect but not appropriate for the context.
